# dnsPython - not working

Tags: python, dnspython

Im working on project where i need to test if domains has IPv6 addresses in MX, AAAA records.
Id like to use Python for script coding. I find out about dnsPython and installed it but it seems not working at all.

when I execute this simple code:

```
import dns.resolver

answers = dns.resolver.query('dnspython.org', 'MX')
for rdata in answers:
    print 'Host', rdata.exchange, 'has preference', rdata.preference
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Python_workspace\Test\Zdroj\bbb.py", line 9, in <module>
    answers = dns.resolver.query('dnspython.org', 'MX')
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\dns\resolver.py", line 920, in query
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\dns\resolver.py", line 847, in query
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\dns\resolver.py", line 692, in _compute_timeout
dns.exception.Timeout
```

I used to code in Java, but there if was some error during compilation I was able to find out what was wrong thanks to error description, but here im lost, I cant find anything useful from error that i could use to find the mistake.
It looks like something is missing, or badly installed libraries.

Comment: SOLVED...

I tried it on another computer connecting to different ISP and worked.
So I tried to troubleshoot my internet connection... after factory reset of my router everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception you are getting is: `dns.exception.Timeout`. This is not a compile error, but a runtime exception. This is probably due to your firewall or router settings disallowing dnspython from making the DNS queries it needs to.

Comment: any suggestions what to do? I already tried turning off firewall but with no result. Got some tips what to try to set on router?
Or what to do to test if the problem is for sure in firewall/router...?

Comment: It's hard for me to say. There are a zillion reasons why the DNS query (or response) packets might be blocked in your setup, none of which I can diagnose from here. The first thing might be to try a completely different internet connection (such as a coffee shop or other location with free wifi, for example). That might tell you whether the problem is your code, or your firewall.